# Is there real footage of Tiangong 1 reentry?

Tags: reentry, tiangong-1

There are a couple of videos on the net showing some reentries and claiming them to be Tiangong 1. Is any of them authentic?

I could not find any footage on the websites of the major space agencies (CNSA, NASA, ESA) nor on general or space news websites.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/E7xxi I saw this on Imgur, but it's unsourced (obviously).

Comment: Similarly, this one: https://imgur.com/gallery/aDyCJ (also unsourced)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**As of this point we do not have actual footage of the reentry.**

It occurred somewhere over the Pacific Ocean, there is very little to no population there. [Almost no planes](https://twitter.com/nextspaceflight/status/980617127416786944?s=21) were at the reentry point. Maybe per coincidence some fisherman or island inhabitant just happened to catch it, but I think it is unlikely.

There is some fake footage, mostly consisting of people filming planes, or shining flashlights at clouds.

A few space agencies and especially the US military probably have some satellite imagery showing a fireball, but will not release it.

A fireball *may* have been spotted in publicly available satellite imagery. See [this twitter thread](https://twitter.com/jccwrt/status/980679680931049472?s=21).

Answer (score 2):

The Fraunhofer Institute for High Frequency Physics and Radar Techniques near Bonn, Germany released a picture from a distance of 270 kms.

[image: Tiangong-1 - 270 kms from earth's surface]

There is some interesting information about how they tracked it in [space.com](https://www.space.com/40168-china-space-station-tiangong-1-crash-tracking.html)

Comment: That's a relatively-high-altitude (270 km/170 mi) radar image, not a re-entry photograph.

Comment: This isn't a image of the re-entry.

Comment: I've just asked [Detailed radar imaging of Tiangong-1; how do they do that?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31921/12102)